# Google Script concat severaly arrays of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, google-apps-script

I am struggling with the following task: I have an folder with 20 spreadsheets that have all a datatable with the same format (same columns). I want to loop through all of them, collect the data, combine it to one big array and display it on a spreadsheet.

However, I am struggling to combine the arrays. In the first step I load the column headers from the final sheet. Afterwards I loop through all files (I have a table with the sheets ID stored in the array aFiles) but I cannot combine the arrays. I tried it with `aData.concat` but it didn't do anything.

```
function getInformation(){

var ssZ = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sZu = ssZ.getSheetByName("Meldeeinheiten");
var aFiles = sZu.getDataRange().getValues();
var sDa = ssZ.getSheetByName("Data_komplett")

var aData = sDa.getRange(1, 1, 1, 15).getValues()

for (var iFile = 1; iFile<aFiles.length; iFile ++){
     var org = aFiles[iFile][0];
     var name = aFiles[iFile][1]; 
     var id= aFiles[iFile][2]; 

     var ssI = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
     var sData = ssI.getSheetByName("Data");
     var lRow = sData.getLastRow();
     if (lRow >= 2){
         var aNew =[];
         aNew = sData.getRange(2, 1, sData.getLastRow(), 15).getValues();
         aData.concat(aData,aNew);
          }
     }
  var lDRow = sDa.getLastRow();
  sDa.getRange(2, 1, lDRow , 15).clear()

  var rng = sDa.getRange(1, 1, aData.length, 15);
  rng.setValues(aData);
  Logger.log(aData.length)

  }
```

The data in the tables is strucutred in the following way:

```
Spreadsheet A:
Org   Name    Hours   Comment
A     Joe     15      Weekend
A     Pete    20      Sunday
A     Maik    15      test

Spreadsheet B
Org   Name    Hours   Comment
B     Will    15      Monday
B     Anna    18      holiday
B     Dave    10      test

...
```

And so one.

Has anybody an idea how I can combine those data and create a "joint database"?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about your question. So can I ask you about it? 1. Can you provide the result you expect? 2. What is "Spreadsheet A" and "Spreadsheet B" in below table? 3. What is "joint database"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

```
aData.concat(aData,aNew);
```

[`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)  doesn't concat in-place. It `return`s the concatenated array.

#### Solution:

Use the returned array:

```
aData = aData.concat(aData,aNew);
```

Alternatively use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap),

```
const out = aFiles.flatMap(([org, name, id])=>
SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
  .getSheetByName('Data')
  .getDataRange()//TODO Modify range according to last row
  .getValues())
```